# Как выбрать текст, используя только CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть номер телефона:

```
<div class="phone">
+7(499)111-22-33
</div>
```

Можно ли как-нибудь, используя только *CSS* (не вмешиваясь в *html*-разметку и не прибегая к *js*), изменить только код города, скажем, сделать шрифт другим цветом?

Какой-нибудь селектор, или вроде того.

Comment: div .phone{ color: #c1c1c1 }

Comment: Обратиться к букве, не оборачивая ее в теги не получится

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, никак. Придётся в любом случае добавить дополнительный `<span>` или `<mark>` тег. Без добавления тегов не получится, т.к. внутри `div` нет *DOM* элементов, по строке *css* не работает, за исключением одного случая: псевдо-селектора `:first-letter`. При помощи него вы можете поменять первый символ - `+` в вашем случае, например так:

```
div.phone:first-letter {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

Если же менять разметку - то всё просто:

```
div.phone>span.cityCode {
    color: #0f0;
}

<div class="phone">
    +7(<span class="cityCode">499</span>)110-29-68
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не получится.

Селекторы CSS работают только с целыми элементами, выделить какую-то текстовую часть и изменить ее свойства не получится без дополнительной разметки.

Answer (score 1):

Есть способ-костыль с ипользованием псевдоэлементов (::before, :after) - правда за такое на кострах жгут:

```
.phone {
    position: relative;
}
.phone:before {
    content: '432';
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #0f0;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 8px;
}
```

Еще раз повторюсь - способ костыльный, по сути он не меняет текста, а добавляет новую сущность, которая закроет собой, то что нужно заменит. Способ подойдет только для страницы с однородным фоном (этот цвет нужно будет задать как фоновый для елемента `.phone:before`), так же используется абсолютное позиционирование, и нужно будет вручную подбирать позиции сверху и слева, причем изменение размера шрифта, да вообще любое изменение может привести к поломке